# At any point during studying, is it okay to just give up?

Tags: motivation

Is it okay to just say "I know what I know, and I'm not gonna try to learn anymore, because I'm already so exhausted as it is"? I'm asking this because this is basically how I feel right now, and several other times, I don't know if I'm even gonna make any more progress. Has anyone ever been in a similar situation? What do you end up doing? What would you recommend?

Comment: Sounds like burnout. What stage of your career are you in? When's the last time you took more than a week off?

Comment: Sleep is really important!

Comment: Are you talking about short term or long term? If you're talking about "I have a test tomorrow and I'm going to call it quits here," that's perfectly normal. If you're saying "I've feel like I've been stuck doing the same thing last 6 months and I haven't learned *anything*," then cag51's comment is definitely relevant.

Answer (score 8):

If you cram right up to the moment of the exam you will probably perform sub optimally. You will probably remember only what you studied last, not what you learned overall. Give your mind and body time to decompress before the exam. A day might be appropriate. Your mind won't quit working just because you aren't trying to drive it unmercifully.

In general, take regular breaks if you have a long study regimen such as for a qualifying exam. An hour or so every few hours. Use some physical activity to get your blood moving and to get  you breathing hard. Then you can return refreshed to study.

It isn't giving up. It is just using your capabilities more efficiently.

This sort of thing has been studied extensively.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I wonder about the "I don't know if I'm even gonna make any more progress" more than about the being "exhausted". It might be helpful to rethink how you study, well, more than whether it's okay to stop when you are exhausted (sure, but this doesn't mean that studying this way is a good overall strategy, nor that you will pass if you continue to work this way).

It's a trite saying to "work smarter, not harder" but I think this YouTube Video of Marty Lobdell covers this issue well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlU-zDU6aQ0

It's something I wish I would have had during my time as a student.

And hey, given the age of this question — did stopping (or not stopping) work out for you?